# Can division of two generic polynomials be expressed as another polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

**The exact problem I am having:**
$C(x)=1+ c_1x$ and $D(x)=1 + d_1 x$, where $c_1, d_1 \ll 1$ but $c_1 x$ or $d_1 x$ can be comparable to unity for large values of $x$, so can't use binomial expansion trivially. All I want to parametrize $D(x)/C(x)$ using a polynomial preferably. The whole purpose of requiring a polynomial is that we then can use orthonormal bases while fitting.

In the future I have to deal with $C(x)$ and $D(x)$ being higher order polynomials, so a solution which can be applied to a couple of generic $n$th order polynomials would be highly beneficial.

Comment: Suppose $D / C = P$, then $D = C \cdot P$. What could the degree of $P$ be?

Comment: Generally, division leads to a quotient **and a remainder**.

Comment: Sorry, there was typo which has been fixed now. $D$ is also a 1st order polynomial here.

Comment: I added the exact problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @SatadruBag After the edit, it's still not clear what form you are looking for that would be simpler than $\dfrac{1 + d_1x}{1+c_1x}=\lambda+\dfrac{1-\lambda}{1+c_1x}$ with $\lambda = \dfrac{d_1}{c_1}$.

Comment: Neither. I am looking for an approximated polynomial $D(x)/C(x) \approx \sum_{n} E_n x^n$ where $n$ can be negative. The whole purpose of requiring a polynomial is that we then can use orthonormal bases while fitting.

Comment: @SatadruBag You'll have to decide what question you mean to ask, then write it down all at once rather than piecewise. Short answer is that's (quite obviously) not possible in the general case. Even in your simple 1st degree example, the fraction $D/C$ is bounded at $\pm \infty$ while any (non-constant) polynomial "approximation" would be unbounded. If you are not talking about the general case, then include the specific details that (you think) might make it possible in your particular case.